Wiremock. как передать параметр из запроса в другой запрос?
{
    "mappings": [
        {
            "scenarioName": "MyTestScenario",
            "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
            "newScenarioState": "Captured",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "urlPath": "/authoreze",
                "queryParameters": {
                    "nonce": {
                        "matches": ".*"
                    }
                }
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "body": "Nonce received {{request.query.nonce}}",
                "transformers": [
                    "response-template"
                ],
                "transformerParameters": {               
                    "nonce": "{{request.query.nonce}}"                  
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "scenarioName": "MyTestScenario",
            "requiredScenarioState": "Captured",
            "newScenarioState": "Started",
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "urlPath": "/token"
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "body": "Nonce value: {{scenarioState.nonce}}",
                "transformers": [
                    "response-template"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Как можно передать значение параметра nonce из запроса на /authoreze на запрос /token?
Использую wiremock-state-extension-standalone-0.8.0.jar и wiremock-jwt-extension-standalone-0.1.0.jar
Сейчас на запрос /token приходит только Nonce value:
